# My one year old daughter is allergic to my beard. How to deal with such issue?

Tags: infant, father, allergies

Everytime I kiss my daughter her skin turns red like she has eczema, short or long beard it changed nothing. Shaving my beard completely is not an option because I also have sensitive skin and without a beard I get all kinds of spots and redness.

Is there some kind of cream/lotion that can protect her skin from my spikes?

Comment: Out of curiosity: How long is "long"? If I remember correctly there comes a point when a beard gets "softer"...

Comment: Hm.  Is there beard conditioner??

Comment: why can't you give up your bead for your daughter? Sacrifice it.. what else is important than our child in the world?

Comment: @version.beta in my job they care a lot of the face/beard, I can't go to work with all kind of spot on my face. If it was not for my job I would not be able to raise my little angel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this issue with both of my sons.

If you're talking about small, red, splotchy spots on her face that are not raised or bumpy in any way, then you're probably not looking at an *allergy*, but merely skin irritation.

[Facial hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_hair) can be thicker and more coarse than body or head hair. This coarseness is abrasive, and so it irritates the skin.

Here's what works for me:

- Do not shave or trim too close. The shorter your beard hair, the stiffer it's going to be. When it's stiff, the ends of the hairs are going to stand out and be more abrasive. Long hair will "bend", so the tips are pointed away. Also, as it gets longer and ages, it starts to break down more, causing the ends to be softer and thinner.
- Do not let your beard get too long. Long beards can be unwieldy when trying to kiss your little ones.
- Once you find a balanced length, avoid nuzzling-type kiss. When you get in too close, especially if you're smooshing cheeks with your pursed lips, it's almost inevitable that there'll be some rubbing.
- Try quick pecks or kisses in other spots. I find the top of the head rarely causes this problem, as it curves away from the beard and avoids the irritation.
- Cover your beard, especially your chin, with your hand as you give smooches. This will block the worst offenders of your beard hair.

You could try other things to softer your hair. There are a number of beard-grooming products that supposedly make your hair softer or shinier, just like other hair-care products. You'd want a product that smooths the [cuticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuticle_(hair)), the outer layer of hair comprised of dead cells. I can't recommend a particular lotion, oil, or condition, but there's a variety to find.

However, if you use a beard-care product you're going to want to make sure that the product itself won't cause chemical irritation. Personally, I just wash my beard with soap and water. The soap and abrasion helps to break down the tough cuticle, leaving the softer inner hair more exposed.

I would also note that my boys have *never* been distressed about the marks, which go away in 5-10 minutes. My older son is old enough now to understand that my beard tickles, so sometimes he actually *likes* when my beard rubs his skin, even though it leaves the irritation spots.

Answer (score 0):

Some people get skin irritation from quite mild scratches. Along with a reasonably large portion of the population I get a slightly milder version of the picture bellow. It runs in the family a little and is quite painless and goes away after 20-30 minutes.

[image: Raised skin]

Does it actually hurt her or cause her discomfort? If not it may not be anything to worry about.

Comment: You might want to add that this is called ["dermographism"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatographic_urticaria). Speaking from experience it can look horribly, but is ["mostly harmless"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy). To check, scratch your baby's arm lightly (e.g. with the back of your fingernail). Often a whiteish trace can be seen right where you scratched, the welt should become visible within a few minutes and disappear in about 15-30 minutes.